# Is there a configuration-free way to distribute a private go CLI?

Tags: go, github, github-actions, homebrew, goreleaser

I have a CLI written with go within a private repository in an organization at Github. I want to distribute this CLI to other developers who have access to this repository.

I tried using goreleaser with a brew tap but it required extra configurations both for Formulas and for users to add their github token via `machine github.com login`. I want to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is probably a better way.

You could include a `.github/workflow/release.yaml` file that looks like this:

```yaml
name: Release MyBinaryName

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  releases-matrix:
    name: Release Go Binary
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        goos: [linux]
        goarch: [amd64]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: wangyoucao577/go-release-action@v1.16
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          goos: ${{ matrix.goos }}
          goarch: ${{ matrix.goarch }}
          project_path: "."
          binary_name: "MyBinaryName"
          ldflags: "-s -w"
          extra_files: LICENSE README.md
```

It would then create downloadable assets whenever [a new release is created in github](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository).

More info on this specific github action [here](https://github.com/wangyoucao577/go-release-action#advanced-example).

There are others like it, or you could [write your own](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-build).

Comment: I was already able to do this with the goreleaser action. My main problem is delivering the executable binaries to other developers systems. The whole process of downloading, unzipping, and copying into /usr/local/bin is very time consuming for every update.